# How to handle dropdown using <span> tag in HTML?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```html
<span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-office_id-container" title="--select--">--select--</span>
<span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span>
```

I am trying with below code, but unable to select dropdown

---

```java
WebElement e1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='select2-office_id-container']"));
Actions a1=new Actions(driver);
a1.click(e1).sendKeys("Office of the Civil Registrar-cum-Sub Registrar,Sattari", Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

---

Comment: Could you detail better the target DOM structure? From these two span, one cannot properly understand how to insert the text.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know (modify the xpath and the values as per your code) -- I've made this to handle similar dropdown:

```java
Thread.sleep(4000);
String options = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='select2- results']")).getText();
System.out.println(options);

for (int i = 0; i < options.length(); i++) {
   WebElement cityName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='select2-results']/ul/li[" + (i+1) + "]"));
   try{
       if (cityName.getText().equals("Chandigarh")) {
            cityName.click();
            break;
       }
   }catch (Exception e){
       System.out.println("ABC");
   }
}
```